# Grails 3.2 File Upload Error (FileNotFoundException )

Tags: java, grails

I'm trying to run a Grails 3.2 web application with Tomcat 8 on Windows 10 that involves file upload. The webApp launches correctly but when I try to upload any file remotely I keep getting the file error below. Notice in the message there are two absolute paths jammed together, which would make for an invalid file specification. I do not get this error when I access the application inside the host machine using localhost as the IP address. Any help is appreciated.

```
<g:uploadForm name="sstForm" controller="sstSetup" method="POST" >
    <input id="w-mdf" type="file" name="wMDF" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <div class="yui3-u-25-100" id="setup-submit">
        <g:actionSubmit class="input block-page" name="submit" value="Submit" action="setupAction" onclick="return validateInput();"/>
        <g:actionSubmit class="inputGrey block-page" name="cancel" value="Cancel" action="cancel"/>
    </div>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Then on the server side I grab the MultiPart file object in the controller and call tranferTo to convert it to a normal file

```
File fileDest = new File("Path to some destination and file name")

multipartFile.transferTo(fileDest)
```

Nothing complicated here. Yet it is throwing FileNotFoundException when the upload is coming from a remote location.

> Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\Users\RWSK70\Documents\Clark\CIM\Misc\Drools\DroolsIntelliJProject\drools-app\target\classes\rules\C:\Users\RWSK70\Documents\Clark\!!\CIM\Misc\Drools\DroolsIntelliJProject\drools-app\src\rules\application\1233275_RSF_v243.txt
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: There are any number of reasons that might happen.  You will have to show some relevant code in your app to get a reliable answer.

Comment: There is not much custom code involved in the upload other than Grails 3 boiler plate code for file upload.

Comment: `new File("Path to some destination and file name")` - You left out the interesting part.  Is the path hardcoded or is it the value of some variable(s)?

Comment: The file path is not hard coded. The grails 3 web form presents a file chooser that is used to point the application to the location of the input file. Any file path throws the same error if it is not from the app host machine (localhost). Weird.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.  If you think it is a problem with the framework, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and link to a sample app which demonstrates the behavior and we can get it straightened out.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid Windows path with two drive references in it: `D:\Users\...C:\Users\...`

Comment: I recognize the first part of the path "D:\Users\RWSK70\Documents\Clark\CIM\Misc\Drools\DroolsIntelliJProject\drools-app\target\classes\rules\" as the temporary directory where the uploaded file is supposed to be transferred to. The second part is the path of the remotely uploaded file. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: I should add that this issue only shows up in the production environment which I have no control over. The application works fine outside this environment. Wondering why the path to the uploaded file should be visible to Tomcat as shown by the jammed up link I posted earlier. Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue. It was caused by the way I handled the uploaded Multipart file. The Servlet specification gave clients the leeway to return either the filename or the absolute path of the file when multipart.getOriginalFilename() is called. I made the erroneous assumption that clients will always return the simple filename based on experience. This is a wrong assumption. It turned out that in this one production environment, their browsers were sending the absolute path of the file instead of the simple filename which the application was expecting and that did not go well. – Felix Andrews Dec 2 at 18:53